# HttpServletRequest returning no cookies - but they exist

Tags: java, servlets

We have a portlet based application that retrieves a certain cookie for validation and then sends off an action request afterwards.

However, we're seeing an issue where the HttpServletRequest is returning a null list of cookies - even though I can 100% confirm there are cookies. In fact, sometimes the code DOES work and shows the cookies (although this is pretty rare).

We've noticed that IE appears to work more frequently than FF and Chrome, but again, there's no consistency or pattern really to determine what causes it to function.

The Request is always obtained - there's never an issue here of a null pointer. The only issue at this moment is that the cookie list is empty.

**Method in static class that returns HttpServletRequest**

```
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    Map<String, Object> requests = context.getExternalContext().getRequestMap();
    for (String requestName : requests.keySet()) {

        if (requests.get(requestName) instanceof HttpServletRequest) {
            return ((HttpServletRequest) requests.get(requestName));
        }
    }
    return null;
```

**Call from the other class to the static method above:**

```
        Cookie[] cookies = StaticClass.getHttpRequest().getCookies();
        System.out.println("Cookies = " + cookies);
```

Comment: forget about the java code for a while and start with checking HTTP traffic. Why is the end user browser not sending the cookies? How are you setting them?

Comment: And when you have that, add relevant information to the question as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HttpServletRequest method getCookies() should return an array of cookies the client sent in on the request. If the array returned is null, it means that the request the client sent in contains no cookies.  Did you call addCookie(yourCookie) method within the same domain or subdomain (I ask as you cannot access cookies across different domains)?

ie:
`Cookie yourCookie = new Cookie(name, value);`
`response.addCookie(yourCookie);`

If the cookie was not added to a previous response, it will not be on the request.

Comment: This particular cookie is added via a 3rd party Javascript call we use. The cookie is there - but is it NOT added in the request?

Comment: @user2124871, please check cookie path, request uri should match it. Try setting the coookie path to "/" for testing purposes.

Comment: @user2124871, it sounds like you're using the 3rd party JavaScript to directly set the cookie in the browser.  If that is the case, then as Osw says, check the cookie path and domain.  Also check to make certain the cookie is actually in the browser.  The only way the cookie will be sent in the request to the server is if the browser is pointed by the user to the exact same path and domain as set in the cookie.  Once the cookie is resent to the server, it is accessible via the getCookies() method.

Answer (score 0):

Some other clues:

1. Check your Cookie's max age. Cookie may be expired.
2. Check the domain of the cookie and the domain of the request URL. If you are not sure, post them here for help.

In general if you can capture the http request message and post it here it will also be helpful.

Update: in firefox you can right click a page, and select 'view page info', then select the 'security' tab, click the 'view cookies' button to view all the cookies. You can also change the domain name in the popup window to see the cookies under other domain.